# Bad layout in users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Text truncated like so:

[image: users]

from [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users).

Comment: Me too: Windows, Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed on live server.